# R replace an id value with a name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which holds an id and a result:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,4,3,3,2,1),result=c(90,75,45,56,78,66))
df
```

I also have a key which holds a name for each id:

```
key <- data.frame(id=c(1:4),name=c("Jon","Fred","Jane","Jim"))
key
```

How can I replace an id value in df with a name value from the key?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> df[["id"]] <- key[ match(df[['id']], key[['id']] ) , 'name']
> df
    id result
1  Jon     90
2  Jim     75
3 Jane     45
4 Jane     56
5 Fred     78
6  Jon     66
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `merge`:

```
merge(df, key)[-1]
```

(The `-1` removes the ID column in the merged data frame.)

Answer (score 2):

you could

```
merge(df,key,by="id" ,all = TRUE)
```

then remove or change names of columns as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

```
 df$id <- ave(df,df$id,
        FUN = function(x)  as.character(key$name[key$id==unique(x$id)]))[1]

df
    id result
1  Jon     90
2  Jim     75
3 Jane     45
4 Jane     56
5 Fred     78
6  Jon     66
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you could use *join* functions:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  full_join(key, by = 'id') %>%
  select(-id)
```